# Mongoose Model.find() throws a UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose with NodeJS, I've connected to my Atlas Database and managed to create a collection containing some entries. The problem is while using
`MyModel.find((err,data)=>err?console.log(err):console.log(data))`
node throws the error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoInvalidArgumentError: Method "collection.find()" accepts at most two arguments.
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which 
was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection.
```

I've tried many methods including: Adding a `.then().catch()` block to `Model.find()` and/or to `mongoose.connect()`; using `Model.find()` inside an async function ; removing/ changing the Callback function inside `Model.find`. But nothing did work.

NB: Other find methods like `Model.findById()` & `Model.findOne()` somehow work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is facing mongoose version 6.0 So you just have to downgrade the mongoose version. Just run npm uninstall mongoose to uninstall the current mongoose version then run npm i mongoose@5.13.8 this will install the version that will fix your problem

Comment: Still doesn't work, I've tried all possible changes for the : Filter , [projection] , [options] & callback Parameters and it still throws the same error over and over.

Comment: This issue is facing mongoose version 6.0 So you just have to downgrade the mongoose version. Just run npm uninstall mongoose to uninstall the current mongoose version then run npm i mongoose@5.13.8  this will install the version that will fix your problem

Comment: This downgrade fixed the error. Thanks for the help